# Rails user-role system - Same user with multiple Rights on different sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan, rolify

I have a Rails-Application, that serves different sites. E.g.

- www.example1.com
- www.example2.com

These sites are stored in the `Site`-model. Also I have set up a User-Role system, using `Devise`, `Rolify`, and `cancancan`

Now one user can have different Roles on different site. E.g he can be an Administrator on `www.example1.com`, but only a simple user on `www.example2.com`

I am loading the users permissions in the ability-model.
 Now my question is: **Where is this "initialize"-function called?**
I need to give this function an additional parameter `site_id`, so that only the appropriate rights of the site are loaded, not the one of the other side.
**How can I do this?**

**models/ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  # From where is this function called, and how can I adjust this call? 
  def initialize(user, site_id) 
    return false unless user.present?
    user_role = user.users_roles.find_by(site_id: site_id).try(:role)
    user_role.permissions.each do |p|
      if p.permission_subject_id.nil?
        can p.permission_action.to_sym, p.permission_subject_class.constantize
      else
        can p.permission_action.to_sym, p.permission_subject_class.constantize, id: p.subject_id
      end
    end unless user_role.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's initialized using the current_ability method. So you need to overwrite that helper in the application_controller like so

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #...

  private

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, request. original_url)
  end
end
```